# Display more than one value in single row in tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6

I have dynamic values in array. I have to display 4 values in one row and remaining value in another row.

for eg.
count of array is 10.

1st row contain 1, 2, 3, 4
2nd row contain 5,6,7,8
3rd row contain 9, 10.

But my problem is, i got tableview cell as:

1st row : 1,2,3,4
2nd row: 2,3,4,5
3rd row: 3,4,5,6

I am trying lots of things but not getting exact soultion.

cell for row at indexpath:

```
if (rowcount % 4)
 {
     for (k=0; k<4; k++)
     {
       btnexpand = [[UIButton alloc] init];
       btnexpand = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       btnexpand.frame = CGRectMake(j, 5, 80, 40);
       [btnexpand setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Step %d",[[[[appDelegate.array_proj objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] arr_task] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1+k] taskid]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


       [cell.contentView addSubview:btnexpand];

        j = j + 65;
       }
    }
    else
    {
       for (k=0; k<rowcount%4; k++)
        {
           btnexpand = [[UIButton alloc] init];
           btnexpand = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
           btnexpand.frame = CGRectMake(j, 5, 80, 40);

            [btnexpand setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Step %d",[[[[appDelegate.array_proj objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] arr_task] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1+k] taskid]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


             [cell.contentView addSubview:btnexpand];

              j = j + 65;
       }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
int initialIndex = indexPath.row * 4;
for (int i=initialIndex ; i<initialIndex+4 && i< totalValues ; i++)
{
    //USE i for getting IndexValue


}
```